# AWS Code Deploy Agent Needs ruby 2.x to run and you cant install older version of ruby (Work Around)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, installation, aws-code-deploy

AWS Code Deploy Agent Needs ruby 2.x to run and you cant install older version of ruby with `sudo apt install ruby`

This is a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I can share you the commands to have ruby 2.7 and openssl 1.1 to run AWS CodeDeploy.

```
## Install RVM packages managers for ruby
$> gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
$> dnf install curl gcc bzip2 openssl-devel libffi-devel readline-devel zlib-devel ncurses-devel which
$> curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$> bash

## Install OpenSSL 1.1 and Ruby 2.7 with RVM
$> rvm pkg install openssl
$> rvm install ruby-2.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr

## Install AWS CodeDeploy Agent
$> dnf install chkconfig wget
$> mkdir /opt/aws-codedeploy 
$> cd /opt/aws-codedeploy
$> wget https://aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install
$> chmod +x ./install
$> ./install auto
```

You can modify the "dnf" with your "apt" command and adjust it.
I use RockyLinux 9 (see: [my-repo](https://github.com/SkullDesperados/aws-codeploy-rockylinux9))

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

installing older version of ruby 2.7.1 for code deploy

(1)

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`

(2)

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`
`echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`
`exec $SHELL`

(3)

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build`

(4)

`rbenv install 2.7.1`
`rbenv global 2.7.1`

(5)

If **ERROR**: No acceptable C compiler found use 
`apt-get install build-essential`

If your installation fails again, make sure you install the " libreadline-dev "  and " zlib1g-dev "
dependencies:
`sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev`

**Try step (4) again**

(6)

check for version 
`ruby -v`

(7)

`gem install bundler`

(8)

`rbenv rehash`

(9)

**Finally**
`which ruby`
get the path of your ruby, copy the path

open codeploy agent install file the one you install with wget in your root dir

`cd ~`

and run `sudo nano install`

change the first line `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` to the path you copy `#!/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

and save the file and then install codedeploy agent again `sudo ./install auto > /tmp/logfile`

run `sudo service codedeploy-agent status` to see if it works, Hope it does. **HAPPY CODING !!!**